# Split string into different variables

Tags: c, string

Hey guys! I'm new to C, so i would like help in one problem. I have to separate a string and put him into diferent variables. Imagine,  `Sol 3 5` would result in something like:

```
var1=Sol  
var2=3  
var3=5
```

I tried to use the scanf, but it stoped in the first space :/ .
Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

EDIT: Isn't my homework, i'm just practicing, but i really want to now how I can do this :) . The code I have now is this:

```
int main () {  
    char var1[10],var2[10],var3[10],func;  
    fgets(func, 20, stdin);   
    fscanf(func,"%s %d %d", var1,var2,var3);  
    printf("%s %d %d", var1,var2,var3);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Is this homework? No problem if it is ... just let us know and we'll answer with that in mind.

Comment: Isn't my homework, just practicing :) . I put the code I have now on the topic, to give an ideia of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: This code doesn't look right. Does it even compile? `func` needs to be an array, scanf needs to receive pointers (`&`), var3 and var3 shoudl have been integers and fscanf receives a FILE*, not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the edit and code posted

Your problem is that you are lying to the compiler. Don't do that. It doesn't like it :)

You ask the compiler to read a string and 2 integers ... but then tell it to put the results in a char arrays (correct only for the first conversion)

```
             /* char[] but %d wants pointer to int */
    fscanf(func,"%s %d %d", var1,var2,var3);
                         /* all var1, var2, and var3 are arrays of char! */
```

Try declaring your variables as

```
    char var1[10];
    int var2,var3;
```

Oh! `func` is declared as plain char. You probably want something else.

Once you declare your variables like that, you need to change the `scanf` call an pass the address of the ints, rather than their (uninitialized) values.

Comment: One more **important** thing: you should always test the return value of most Standard C functions; in particular the `scanf` family (also the `malloc` family). So ... write `if (scanf(...) != 3) { /* oops */ }` rather than `scanf(...);`

Answer (score 4):

`strtok` is the function you need:

```
 #include <string.h>

 char* str = "Sol 3 5";
 char* ptr;
 char* saved;
 ptr = strtok_r(str, " ", &saved);
 while (ptr != NULL)
 {
   printf("%s\n", ptr);
   p = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saved);
 }
```

Just a note: this function modifies the original string, placing end of string tokens (nulls, `\0`) in place of delimiters.

Ok `scanf` would be good anyway, but I'm not gonna help you if you don't state clearly if it's homework..

Comment: New code should not use `strtok`.  Use `strtok_r` instead, which does much the same thing but is thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot about reentrancy :)

Comment: @Jack: `srttok` and `strtok_r` have different argument lists; @John: `strtok_r` is POSIX, so not universally (in the C compilers universe) available.

Comment: Isn't my homework, i'm practicing, but i really want to now how do this. In the code you type, the function don't save the string into variable, just print the string right?

Comment: yes, it just prints it but the pointer can be used for your purposes, you can actually dupe it with `strdup` and forget about the fact.

Comment: @pmg: yes, the saved pointer is envolved too but now I'm going out.. if anyone wants to fix it feel free!

Comment: Does line 2 of the loop need a "ptr =" instead of "p ="?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function similar to `scanf` called [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/). It works just the same, but it reads to values from a string instead of from a file:

```
sscanf("Sol 3 5", "%s%d%d", v1, &v2, &v3);
```